# How store work days of week in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have **Shop** entity

I need 7 checkboxes to set working days for this shop on frontend

I'm looking for best solution to store values in db.
The easiest method is to keep 7 boolean fields like "monday?" "tuesday?" ... in db

Can you help me? thanks

PS: it should be searchable (ex. i want all shops working today)

Rails 3, Postgresql 8.4

Comment: serialization is ok - but what if i need to search - it wont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you going to use this data? If you need to find by working day(s) of week then do boolean columns as you say. If you don't, store as a string representation such as 'tttttff' (open monday to friday).

Comment: Thanks. So boolean will be better solution

Comment: It would be by far the better performing solution if you're using them in finds.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's little chance you'll have any kind of useful indexes on it, a bit(7) might be a good candidate depending the type of query you're doing. (And assuming AR supports it.)

Alternatively, boolean fields work - it'll just be a lot more verbose.